# What's the significance of .NET ReaderWriterLock's "-1 milliseconds"

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety

The .NET ReaderWriterLock methods' documentation, such as AquireReaderLock ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cwd104(v=vs.110).aspx ) explicitly mentions a timeout value of -1 milliseconds as a valid timeout, but fails to state what this value represents.

Does this mean that the lock fails immediately, like a TryLock?

Does it mean that the lock will never time out?

The internet has no answer for me!

Comment: It is infinity.  And beyond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never timeout if a value of -1 is supplied.

Per "for valid time-out values, see [ReaderWriterLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx)":

> (-1)
>   The thread waits until the lock is acquired, regardless of how long it takes. For methods that specify integer time-outs, the constant Infinite can be used.

Comment: The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/readerwriterlock.cs,92cf5bf5504c7729,references) is full of comparisons to -1. It seems like it's just a magic number to represent (don't time out).